# How to publish site using Visual Studio 2010 FTP

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ftp, publishing

I have published my website using VS2010 and then selected FTP Site.
Problem is that it does not show me update status. and takes too much time as compare to other FTP client.

**Is there any way or plugin for visual studio 2010 so i can build and directly publish that on FTP server.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Website|Copy Website? I think the reason it is slower because it compares files on both sides to determine which files are newer.

How often do you have to do that. It's a little slow, but seems to work okay for me.

Comment: I just click on Build and Publish Website.

Comment: Maybe you should consider Copy Web Site. It's much faster for publishing incremental changes to your site.